# throws statement for handled exceptions -- Java

Tags: java, exception, throws, checked-exceptions

Suppose the following code:

```
public static void somMethod() throws IOException {

try {
    // some code that can throw an IOException and no other checked exceptions
} catch (IOException e) {
        // some stuff here -- no exception thrown in this block
}

}
```

**someMethod** throws an **IOException**, and no other checked exception, 
and handles that exception itself.

What exactly

```
throws IOException
```

in its declaration is bringing in? 
From what I know, it is making it possible for the methods 
calling **someMethod()** handle that **IOException** themselves.

is anything else happening here?

Comment: If the `catch` block is rethrowing the exception, the `throws IOException` is necessary for any code calling the method.

Comment: no, the catch stat. is clear.

Comment: ..but thx for the point.

Comment: I wish I can answer this, but I can't understand your question. Could you please rephrase or add more detail? Thanks.

Comment: @Nayuki Minase rather asking for verification-- not a Q per se. as plain as it seems, nothing behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the catch block doesn't throw `IOException`, the `throws IOException` part in the method signature is not necessary. And also, every time the `someMethod()` is invoked, there has to be provided a `catch` block for a *possible* exception that actually never occurs.